# catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i am creating a ROS Workspace,while i get the last step as the tutorails say.but ,
my terminal shows:"catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks".
not as the tutorails showed" catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share"
there are extral :"/opt/ros/indigo/stacks"
i dont konw wether i create the ros workspace correctly???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257686/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks/) by [zpzsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/29785/zpzsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is expected. Older ROS versions(fuerte and earlier) had stacks as well.

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2